# Using a Java Library across iPhone and Android app version

Tags: iphone, android, ios, cordova

Good libraries are either written in C or Java a lot of the time. (No offense to Python, javascript, or Erlang).  Well this time the best library for what I am doing is in Java. But I want to use it for both the Android and iPhone version of my app.  How can this be done. This is a very important question because there will always be times when the best library is in Java even for an iPhone app.  I am also open to HTML5 and PhoneGap solution, but essentially I need some way to access a Java Library in both environments. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done.  You cannot run a Java lib on iOS. You will either need to find an equivalent library that is written in C/Objective-C and use the Java one with Android and the C/Objective-C one with iOS, or you'll need to find one that runs on both (JavaScript).

If you use Java/C solutions you'll then need to create a plugin for each to create a JavaScript API for PhoneGap to talk to.

You can find information about all of this [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [RoboVM](https://robovm.com/) or [j2objc](https://github.com/google/j2objc/) to transpile the Java to Objective C.